# One joint owner moves out

Tags: house

One joint owner moves out and does not contribute to the support of the property for 11 years.
When the house is sold, what share of the proceeds does the moved out joint owner get?

Comment: Whatever the joint owners agree to. But absent any agreements to the contrary, I would assume that if there are 2 joint owners, each has a 50% share of the property, and so each is entitled to 50% of the sale proceeds.

Comment: In any case, it's a matter of contract law, not finance, so it greatly depends on the jurisdiction.

Comment: location is important for this, and so is "joint owner" - for example, if the owners are married.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a matter pertaining to contract law on a state-level basis.

Answer (score 5):

> One joint owner moves out and does not contribute to the support of the property for 11 years.

That's completely irrelevant to the issue of ownership, and thus distribution of the proceeds of sale.

EDIT: for example, you (probably) owning shares of stock, and get dividends -- aka **money** -- from those shares, even though you don't "contribute to the support of the (company)".  Part ownership of real estate is no different.

> When the house is sold, what share of the proceeds does the moved out joint owner get?

Whatever the joint ownership agreement specifies.  If there is none, call the lawyers.

Heck, call the lawyers anyway, because we're "dogs on the Internet".

Comment: "One joint owner moves out and does not contribute to the support of the property for 11 years." Yeah... this isn't a complete story, I suspect. No mention if said 'joint owner' did anything else -- i.e. pay water/electric/trash/property taxes/gas. Or even if they just kept the house and cooked the meals. There are lots of ways to contribute without directly adding dollars.

Comment: @R.Hamilton "There are lots of ways to contribute without directly adding dollars."  That's completely irrelevant.  Take, for example, owning shares of stock: you get dividends from those shares, even though you don't "contribute to the support of the (company)".

Comment: I think it is extremely relevant. But that is my opinion. And that is the real problem with the scenario spelled out by the OP. Without something written down and agreed to by both parties, it is almost all going to come down to opinions on how much each party feels they contributed, and almost surely one or both of them are going to feel like they are being treated unfairly.